# Initialise font property at IBOutlet

Tags: ios, uilabel

Is there a way to pre-set the text property of a label at it's outlet? below is what I have in mind but it doesnt work because it is the wrong syntax

```
@IBOutlet weak var commentHeaderLbl: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        self.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(8)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your label is in a UIViewController subclass, you could just do this at `viewDidLoad`.

If your label is in a UITableViewCell subclass, you could just do this at `awakeFromNib`.

Example:

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      self.commentHeaderLbl.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(8)
    }
```

If You are using interface builder, it is possible to define the font size there too.

Comment: How about if it is inside UITableHeaderFooterView?

Comment: I guess You meant UITableViewHeaderFooterView. awakeFromNib also ;)

Comment: Works great! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var commentHeaderLbl: UILabel! {
    didSet {

      self.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(8, weight: UIFontWeightThin)

   }
}
```

you can change the weight property as per your need.

Comment: sorry @dirtydanee i misunderstood it, have edited the ans.